# Executing Specific tests in selenium (Maven project in eclipse IDE)

Tags: java, maven, selenium

I am doing automation using Selenium-Java. I have created maven project in eclipse IDE.I am running the test cases using @Test Annotation. When I have number of test cases to be run, I am using`(priority=1,2 and so)` and `enabled=false`which has to be disabled.      Is there any other way to do because If I have let say 100 of tests out of which 50 needs to be run,So I need to disable 50, which is really hectic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group test together using TestNG group and run it.

**OR**

You can use include or exclude methods in testNG.xml file and run the tests from there. You can also use to define Regex to define excluded methods.

**Please refer the testNG documentation -**

http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html

**2.** If you are not using testNG and you want to skip test cases based on methods name you can do as following -

```
@BeforeMethod
public void nameBefore(Method method)
{
    // You can define any condition on which you want to skip your tests.
    if(method.getName().matches("disabled")){
        throw new SkipException("Skipping test method");
    }       
}
```

**3.** If you want to disable all test methods present in entire class then you can use -

```
@Test(enable=false)
class MyClass{
  // Test methods
}
```

Comment: As i have already mention I am using maven project, there is no file called testNG.xml.   Can I have something called customized Test class which will run Test method based on choice?  To be more precise, just by giving test method name?

Comment: I have updated my answer. This might solve your problem